# Not able to convert string to decimal in mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Hi i am working on a MVC project where i stuck on very small issue.I have Item price which is coming in decimal and i also decalred it as decimal.

it all works fine.Price displays perfectly the way i want.

Now the problem is that i dont want to display the price if user is not loged in.

Now the problem is that  ITEM.PRICE COMES LIKE  32.5D

But if user not loged in then i want to display blank here.

I am  trying something like this but its not working:

```
  @If Session("UserData") Is Nothing Then


           item.Price=Decimal.Parse("")                          

   End if
```

Comment: Whats not working (what are you expecting and what is actually happening). Show your controller method and relevant section or the view.

Comment: I'm afraid It's hard to understand what you're trying to do, why you parse an empty string to assign it to a `decimal` property?

Comment: @StephenMuecke  thanks for you reply...i want if user is not loged in them item.price should not visible.so i am trying to pass empty string.Thats only the issue

Comment: If your property is typeof `decimal` it cant be an 'empty string'. Why not just check the condition in the view and either render it or not (although having a view model with a property (say) `bool CanViewPrice` which you set in the controller would be better. The in the view `@if(Model.CanViewPrice) { Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Price) }`

Comment: I think you only have to do is to check if the user is authenticated and if IsAuthenticated then display the price otherwise do nothing and will not display the price.

`@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
  {
        Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Price) 
  }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need nullable decimal property. Use this to declare:

```
Public decimal? Price { get; set; }
```

When parse it:

```
If (string.IsNullOrEmpty(yourString)) {
    item.Price = null;
}
else
{
    item.Price = decimal.Parse(yourString);
}
```

Comment: how to make this item.price=""  or empty

Comment: Again, you need to declare Price to be decimal? instead of decimal